# Using printer on a Windows domain (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, windows, printing, domain-server

I am trying to use a network printer on a Windows AD domain. 
The address is something like:

```
\\\name.ad.int.com
```

or

```
smb://name.ad.int.com/
```

I tried to connect this as a samba printer and also other ways, but somehow can't get it work. I am on 16.04, but not on the Windows domain and I have a different username than my name on the domain. I can connect to the domain via nautilus: Connect to Server. Then I see three folder, one of which is `print$`.

Any advice on how I best connect my computer to use this printer? Thanks.

Comment: Some printers support mutiple protocols, including IPP protocol, so try prepending `ipp://` to it

Comment: this wiki https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu provides guidance, from here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu#Printing_from_Ubuntu for ubuntu to win server